# Why is my PHP Email Form sending a blank email

Tags: php, html, email

Let me first explain my problem.

I had a freelance job where I was designing & developing a website for a business company. I coded an email form and attached it to a PHP sending form, it gathers the Name, Phone, Email, Subject, and Message of whoever fills out the form and sends it to the owner of the business.

Recently the owner has been complaining about receiving blank emails and thinking they are missing business I went back into the PHP code and added a verification system, added even a redirect that when it submits properly it will redirect to a page that has 2 options either "Sorry there has been a Problem" or "thank you for sending the email"

I also went into my HTML and fixed that as well adding "required fields" so there is absolutely no way the email can be sent without things filled in.

Can someone please explain a sure-fire way to explain it because the owner is still complaining about getting blank emails...

This is the HTML CONTACT FORM FILE

```
    <form method="post" action="acknowledge.php"  role="form" class="php-email-form">
      <div class="form-row section-bg">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter a valid Full Name" required/>
          <div class="validate"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cname" id="cname" placeholder="Company Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter a valid Company Name" required/>
          <div class="validate"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Telephone" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter a valid Phone Number" required/>
          <div class="validate"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid Email" required/>
          <div class="validate"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group section-bg">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" placeholder="Message"  required></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="send" value="Send Message"/>
    </form>
```

This is the PHP EMAIL FILE

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
     $to = 'Owners Email';
     $subject = 'Business Inquiries';
     $name = 'Full Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n\r\n";
     $cname = 'Company Name: ' . $_POST['cname'] . "\r\n\r\n";
     $tel = 'Telephone Number: ' . $_POST['tel'] . "\r\n\r\n";
     $emails = 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n\r\n";
     $message = 'Message: ' . $_POST['message'];
     
     $email_from = 'Owners business website name';
    
     $email_body = "$name\n $cname\n $emails\n $tel\n $message\n";

     $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
     $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    
     $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
     if($email) {
         $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: $emails";
     }


     $success = mail($to, $subject, $email_body, $headers);
}

?>
<body>
<?php if (isset($success) && $success) { ?>
<h1>Thank You!</h1>
Your Message has been sent!
<?php } else { ?>
<h1>Oops!</h1>
Sorry, there was a problem sending your message. Please Try Again.
<?php } ?>
</body>
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

Comment: In the PHP check that ALL the fields you use in `$_POST` have data in them. Only send the email if they do.... simples

Comment: if you made an echo of the $email_body variable what are print ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks you for this input all the fields that use $_POST do have data in them are there any other suggestions?

Comment: @Inazo can you elaborate more on this comment?

Comment: This is a strange question you ask: "Can someone please explain a sure-fire way to explain it because the owner is still complaining about getting blank emails..." How should "explaining that your script works" somehow help to solve the issue you have? If empty emails are received you have an issue. Something obviously _is_ broken, whether your script is robust or not. No way to get around that. I really hope that you are _not_ trying to argue along the line "look, the script cannot make mistakes, so you cannot receipt empty mails". He _does_ , you see?

Comment: @arkascha well no i'm asking someone to explain to me a sure-fire way on how to fix the problem, not boasting that my code is flawless cause code can never be flawless

Comment: Then check the content of each used $_POST variable. `Required` works with compliant browser, but not if someone is using a old/bad browser OR a bad actor is not even using your form and just posting nonsense at your `acknowledge.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to check all the required fields to be set something like this, optionally you can check each field to be set.

```
   <?php
   
   $name = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
   $cname = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'cname', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
   $tel = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'tel', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
   $message = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
   $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

   if (!empty($name) && !empty($cname) && !empty($tel) && !empty($message) ) {
        $to = 'Owners Email';
        $subject = 'Business Inquiries';
        $name = 'Full Name: ' . $name . "\r\n\r\n";
        $cname = 'Company Name: ' . $cname . "\r\n\r\n";
        $tel = 'Telephone Number: ' . $tel . "\r\n\r\n";
        $emails = 'Email: ' . $email . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message = 'Message: ' . $message;
        
        $email_from = 'Owners business website name';
       
        $email_body = "$name\n $cname\n $emails\n $tel\n $message\n";
   
        $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';
       
        
        if($email) {
            $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: $emails";
        }
   
   
        $success = mail($to, $subject, $email_body, $headers);
   }
   
   ?>
```